# NetLogo foreach list

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to create a code that will allow me to get the who numbers of 10 turtles and store them in a list. However, the "who" number can only be added to the list if it has not been added to the list before.

I have to use the "foreach" command to check if the number has already been added to the list.

Any suggestions on how to do so?

My code:

```
turtles-own [contact-list]

to setup
  clear-all
  
  create-turtles 10 [
    set contact-list []
    print who
  ]
  
  reset-ticks
end

to go
  ask turtles [
    set contact-list lput [who] of one-of other turtles-here contact-list
    foreach contact-list[
      ; this is where the command goes
    ]
    print contact-list
  ]
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Might it be easier to add all the who numbers to the list and then use the `remove-duplicates` primitive to remove the duplicate numbers?  I assume that you have a reason for putting who numbers into the list rather than having a list of the agents themselves, or an agentset.  In general, who numbers are to be avoided.